# Regex question mark quantifier is not greedy enough

Tags: regex

Optional quantifier as anyone other supposed to be greedy by default, i.e. should match as much as possible.

Let's try to apply `(AB)?.*B` regex to input `AB`.
What I expect is that `(AB)?` will greedily match full string, and there will be no more characters to match for the rest `.*B`.

Actual behavior differs, it matches given input. Why?

Comment: The trailing `B` forces the regex to guarantee that it matches a `B` at the end so in your example it's easier to read your regex from right to left.

Comment: The whole pattern needs to match, that means also the B at the end. When the optional AB matches it continues and try to match the B. That does not match any more and it will backtrack. Then `.*` can match the rest and that can backtrack to match the final `B`

Comment: So, regex is being matched not left-to-right, but in priority order? How it may be forced to match optional group first (and fail matching of this example)?

Comment: If you want `(AB)?` to be important then use `(AB)?.*B?` so that the trailing `B` is less important and now your regex will read from left-to-right.

Comment: @AlexeyAdamovskiy This example has got nothing to do with "greediness" or "priority". If the `(AB)` matches, then the `.*B` part of the regex would not match. Therefore the whole thing would not match.

Comment: @TomLord this is exactly what I expect here. But nonetheless it matches.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `B?` will make `B` optional and given input matching again. This is not what I want to get. What I in general want, is to keep validating input string by an existing regex, but with an optional prefix.

Comment: @AlexeyAdamovskiy It matches, because the `(AB)?` is optional. So, `(AB)?` matches against nothing, `.*` matches against `A` and `B` matches against `B`. In other words, `(AB)?.*B` does match `AB`, but the capture group is blank.

Comment: @TomLord This would explain why it would match input like `XB`. `(AB)?` is optional, but it is greedy. Why should it skip `AB` match? Regex as I believed before should apply leftmost operator first, and this operator fits well.

Comment: I really do not understand what your question is. As it is written you simply misunderstand quantifiers and the regex engine. I suggest playing around at https://regex101.com/ to better understand how regex works. If you wish to update your question with examples of things which should or should not match then I may be able to offer more advice but as it stands you simply do not understand what is being explained to you.

Comment: Even though `(AB)?` is greedy, it is optional so that means it is not required to match.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html is a good reference

Comment: @MonkeyZeus so, thanks, it helped. Thing that gives behavior that I've been expecting from greedy quantifier, is actually "Possessive quantifier". So my regex should be `(AB)?+.*B`

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are asking regex to guarantee a trailing `B`

Let's break it down:

- `(AB)?` - try and give me a sequential `AB`
- `.*` - try and give me zero or more of anything
- `B` - give me `B` or give me death! `B` **must** be matched so `.*` matches the `A` and `(AB)?` is okay with getting nothing

If your input is `ABB` then `AB` would go to capture group #1

---

Had you done:

```
(A|B)?.*B
```

then at least `A` would have went to group #1 but `B` is still explicitly matched by the trailing `B`

Comment: Death, Gore and Vegeance! Using regular expressions is brutality!

Answer (score 1):

Regex

```
(AB)?.*B
```

applied to string

```
AB
```

works like this:

1. There MUST be a `B` at the end.
2. Sequence `AB` can appear once, or not at all.
3. If sequence `AB` is considered to appear once, then a final B does not exist. So the regex engine decides that sequence `AB` does not appear at all.
4. `.*` will match `A`
5. `B` will match `B`